# Contact form 7 getting spam messages while sending message from contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 for mail functionality with in website front end.While sending messages i am getting my mail but also getting mails from others with 200-330 time with no limit for this i have activate Akismet Anti-Spam plugin word press to avoid spam but still getting spam messages.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reCaptcha ? [link](https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/)